# MVC 4 OleDbConnection Issue

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, oledbconnection

I have an issue with data being returned from an Excel spreadsheet. I can read all data with the exception of the first column, for some reason to which I am baffled, `tbl.Rows[r][0]` is actually the second column and `tbl.Rows[r][1]` is the third column and so on.

I have reviewed the spreadsheet to which the following code is attached to, its not corrupt, just a typical Excel 97-2003 spreadsheet and I can confirm the first column (A) is not hidden in any way.

```
var tbl = new DataTable();

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\""))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]", conn))
    {
        adp.Fill(tbl);
    }
    conn.Close();
}

AddData(tbl);

public void AddData(DataTable tbl)
{
    Type typeString = Type.GetType("System.String");
    Type typeDateTime = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
    Type typeBoolean = Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
    Type typeInt32 = Type.GetType("System.Int32");

    var tblData = new DataTable();
    tblData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeString));
    tblData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Created", typeDateTime));
    tblData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedBy", typeString));
    tblData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeInt32));
    tblData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Public", typeBoolean));
    tblData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Note", typeString));

    for (int r = 0; r <= tbl.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        DataRow row = tblData.NewRow();

        row["ID"] = tbl.Rows[r][1].ToString();

        DateTime createDate;
        DateTime.TryParse(tbl.Rows[r][2].ToString(), out createDate);

        row["Created"] = createDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        row["CreatedBy"] = "Bob";

        row["Type"] = 7;

        row["Public"] = false;

        var sbNote = new StringBuilder();
        sbNote.Append("<ul>");
        sbNote.Append("<li>Criteria - " + tbl.Rows[r][4] + "</li>");
        sbNote.Append("<li>Status - " + tbl.Rows[r][6] + " (" + tbl.Rows[r][3] + ")</li>");
        sbNote.Append("<li>Number - " + tbl.Rows[r][0] + "</li>");
        sbNote.Append("<li>ID - " + tbl.Rows[r][1] + "</li>");
        sbNote.Append("</ul>");

        row["Note"] = sbNote.ToString();

        tblData.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    tblData.Dispose();
}
```

I am getting no errors, re the code, just the data from the first column is not being returned, therefore not being read.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Did you check that the range in which the table is defined actually covers the column?

Comment: I haven't specified a range, just `SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]`, is there any way to check the data passed to `tbl` prior to passing to `tblData`?

Comment: Have you tried creating a DataReader and see what it returns directly?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, please see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161066/mvc-excel-cannot-find-column-0` the nightmare continues.